# Number of games required such that two arbitrary players play together and against each at least once.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2N$ players to form two teams of $N$ players that play against each other in a game. How many games are required such that two arbitrary players play together and against each other at least once?

Comment: In each game, is each player from the first team randomly assigned a player from the second game to play against? Is each game different from the previous one?

Comment: I believe he wants all 2N players involved in every game.  With 4 players, simplest case, you need three games:  (a,b) vs (c,d) , (a,c) vs (b,d), and (a,d) vs (b,c).  If I am reading the question correctly.

Comment: Maybe you could calculate it by hand for some small values of $N$, then look up your answer in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: If there are $2^n$ players we need $n+1$ games. I think this is a good hint, I haven't solved it yet, but I am willing to work through the problem with you.

Comment: I wrote [Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/aea324a20aeb6ea43aab) to determine the first few values. They are $3,5,4,5,5,6,5$ for $N=2,\ldots,8$. The high values $n+3$ for $N=2^n-1$ are interesting. OEIS doesn't seem to know this sequence.